# Is it possible that $x,y\notin W$ but $x-y=w\neq0\in W$?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $V$ is a vector space and $W$ is a nontrival subspace of $V$. Let $T$ be a linear operator on $V$.

Is it possible that $x,y\notin W$ but $x-y=w\neq0\in W$?

If $W$ is an $T$-invariant subspace of $V$, will the situation be different?

> Define $\bar{T}:V/W\to V/W$ by $\bar{T}(v+W)=T(v)+W$.
> Show that $$[T]_\gamma=
>     \begin{pmatrix}
>     B_1 & B_2 \\
>     O & B_3  \\
>     \end{pmatrix}
> $$
> ,where $B_3=[\bar{T}]_\alpha$, $\{v_1,\cdots,v_k\}$ is a basis for $W$, $\gamma=\{v_1,\cdots,v_k,v_{k+1},\cdots,v_n\}$, $\alpha=\{v_{k+1}+W,\cdots, v_n+W\}$

For $\bar{T}(v_{k+i})=T(v_{k+i})+W$, if we first choose $T(v_{k+i})=\sum_{i=1}^na_iv_i$, then $$\bar{T}(v_{k+i})=T(v_{k+i})+W=(\sum_{i=1}^na_iv_i)+W=(\sum_{i=k+1}^na_iv_i)+W$$ is obvious.

If we choose $T(v_{k+i})+W=(\sum_{i=k+1}^na_iv_i)+W$. I want to show that $T(v_{k+I})=\sum_{i=k+1}^na_iv_i$, I should prove $$T(v_{k+i})-\sum_{i=k+1}^na_iv_i=0\in W$$ and it make me think about the question above I have mentioned.

Comment: What have you tried, and where are you stuck? A bare question probably won't attract good answers.

Comment: Yes to the first question. And I can give examples of $T$ such that it does not change the answer to the previous part

Comment: In $\mathbb R^2$, $y-$axis is a subspace(call it $W$) . Clearly, $(-1,1), (-1,5)\notin W$ but their difference is on $y-$axis.

Comment: Is it still possible when I write down the question I'm thinking about?

Answer (score 1):

Consider in $\mathbb{R}^2$ the subspace $W=\langle e_1\rangle$ and the vectors $e_1+e_2$ and $e_1-e_2$.

For what concerns the second part of the question, in general, you cannot say anything:

In  $\mathbb{R}^2$ consider the same situation in the above counterexample and the operator that sends $e_1$ to $e_1$ and $e_2$ to $-e_2$.